# Meaning of wall colors in Flashpoint?

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, flashpoint

The show Flashpoint is about a fictional SRU team (essentially SWAT).

When they are on location at an incident, they refer to the various walls of a building using colors instead of directions. ("white wall" or "blue wall" instead of "North wall" or "South wall").

**Why do they use colors, and what do the colors mean?**

Is this an actual SWAT team practice?

Answer (score 2):

From reading numerous special forces fiction books, this does happen.

When performing recon, the team will designate easily rememberable (and distinctly worded) names to relevant targets or positions.  This saves team members from having to look at their compass to work out whether a wall/building is North/South/East/West.

The choice of names is usually fairly obvious.  In this case, I'm guessing that aspects of these walls have white or blue items associated with them.